# Boost::asio SSL Connection to Facebook behaves strangely

Tags: c++, facebook, boost-asio

I'm using boost::asio to make async http requests to Facebook (mainly exchanging a client side token for one I can make API calls with). Most of the time it works just fine, returning almost instantly with the data.

However sometimes it hangs at the connect process for 3 or 4 seconds before returning (keep in mind this is SSL). Other times it will even come back with a "Connection refused" error. This is with passing the same data each time (my own facebook token for local testing).

I'm not sure if I messed something up (my code is almost an identical copy to the examples on boost's website) or if this is because of Facebook. Is it common for Facebook servers to hang on a connection to the point where it may time out?

My connection code looks like this:

```
m_sslSocket.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
m_sslSocket.set_verify_callback(boost::asio::ssl::rfc2818_verification(a_server));

boost::asio::async_connect(m_sslSocket.lowest_layer(), a_endpointIterator, boost::bind(&BoostHttpRequest::HandleConnect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

Considering it works most of the time and it's hanging on connect I would guess it's an issue with Facebook and not the code. Anyone who works with making Facebook API calls could toss in their two cents?

Comment: what version of ssl are you using have you disabled v2 ? what about tls ?